# Replacing NA with a value - R

Tags: r, na

Is there a way that I can replace missing values in a vector by randomly sampling from the rest of the data?

e.g

```
age<-c(4.2,5.6,NA,8.4,9.8,NA,10.4,15.3)

age[is.na(age)]<-sample(age,length(age[is.na(age)]),replace=TRUE)  ## trying to replace NA values with a random value from age.
```

I don't understand why this does not work?  Ideally I would like each NA value to be replaced by a different value.

Comment: `age[is.na(age)] <- sample(age[!is.na(age)], length(age[is.na(age)]), replace=F)`

Comment: @akrun, `sum` might make more sense than `length` in this case.

Comment: @AnandaMahto to clarify (for others), you mean `sum(is.na(age))`, right?

Comment: @Ananda Mahto. Yes, that would be compact.  `sample(age[!is.na(age)], sum(is.na(age)), replace=F)`

Comment: @DavidRobinson, yes. akrun should go ahead and post as an answer though....

Comment: @Si_never_sighs: Just curious. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
age[is.na(age)] <- sample(age[!is.na(age)], sum(is.na(age)), replace=F)
```

`sum(is.na(age))` suggested by @Ananda Mahto

Answer (score 0):

In cases where random sampling is undesirable you might replace them with means, medians, or even a model fit:

```
library(e1071)
?impute
impute(as.matrix(age),what="mean") # replaces with mean 8.95
```

or

```
library(randomForest)
?na.roughfix
na.roughfix(age) # replaces with median 9.1
```

If `age` is a predictor and you have responses you could use random forest to impute

```
library(randomForest)
?rfImpute
```

Comment: Thank you.  That's immensely helpful.